# In Android In-App Billing, how can I get back all the payments for a subscription product?

Tags: android, in-app-billing, subscription

Before I explain my question, let me give an example situation.

A user of a magazine app subscribes to the monthly subscription on the month of August and September. If the user reformats the phone, the app should be able to restore both August and September month's magazines.

The problem with this is that, the In-App Billing API returns only the latest subscription and whether the subscription is active.

Also, I want the users to be able view the previous months' magazines even if they have canceled their subscription.

Is there a way to keep track of all payments made by the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This likely would involve your own independent servers and "developer payload" information. As stated in this [Subscriptions link](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html):

Include business logic in your app to notify your backend servers of subscription     purchases, tokens, and any billing errors that may occur. Your backend servers can use the server-side API to query and update your records and follow up with customers directly, if needed.

In other words, you should be keeping track of this--unfortunately.

Further, you can check [this](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/v1/) api reference as to whether a user's subscription purchase is valid.

Comment: Hey man, thanks for the reply.

I was aware of this but I needed someone experienced to clarify this for me.

And its very unfortunate. Hope Android releases an update with this feature in.